# How to call a stored procedure using a ref cursor in Oracle with squirrel

Tags: oracle, ref-cursor, squirrel-sql

I'm trying to do the same request I'm using in Toad

(the stored procedure signature is two varchar2 parameter and one REF CURSOR parameter)

Here is what I do with Toad

```
variable myCursor refcursor;
EXEC myproc('param1','param2',:myCursor );
print myCursor;
```

I don't know how to write this with Squirrel and I have to use Squirrel.

Thanks a lot for your response

Raphaël

Comment: I would like to know this as well...

Answer (score 2):

The only syntax I get working in Squirrel SQL is **PL/SQL block:**

```
declare
v_param1  varchar2:='param';
v_param2  varchar2:='param';
TYPE ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
v_cur_results ref_cursor;
begin
MyProc (v_param1  , v_param2 , v_cur_results)
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

If the tool does not support this facility the next best thing would be to create a proc that will output your cursor for you.

Luckly it has already been written for you. 
see rc_to_dbms_sql( in 
http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=505